Cron expression to run every friday starting from fixed date
I want to create a cron expression to run every friday starting from 25th October at 01:00 AM. Here is the expression I came up with but it is giving error. Kindly help.
0 0 1 25/1 10 6


cron doesn't actually support a specific start date - are you actually using cron or something cron-like with additional options? You could run a cron job to update the cron jobs with a weekly one on that date though.

This question is similar to: Check for date range with bash scripting. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As cron does not directly support start running on a specified date, you can run the cron every Friday at 1 AM and check if the date is on or after 25th October inside your script.  Expression to run the script every Friday at 1 AM is as follows.
0 1 * * 5

An example code to check if the date is on or after 25th October in php is as follows.
<?php
     $targetDate = new DateTime('2023-10-25'); 
     $currentDate = new DateTime();

     if ($currentDate >= $targetDate) {
        // Run your logic
     } else {
        exit();
     }
?>

